# Unable to set the width of scroll View iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am unable to set the width of the scrollView to the width of the screen. Could someone please guide where I am going wrong ?

[image]

Here is how I have enabled a scroll view

```
// SCROLL VIEW
var scrollView = UIScrollView()
var contentView = UIView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    screenHeight    = screenSize.height
    screenWidth     = screenSize.width

    // SCROLL VIEW
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)

   // Here I am adding all my labels and textview fields to content view
   contentView.addSubview(problemDescriptionStackView)
   ....

    // Adding content view to the scrollView
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

    // Pinning the contentView to the scroll view
    pinView(contentView, to: scrollView)

    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    // Here I am Setting the constraints for all the items in the contentView
    ....
}
```

// The below functions are used to pin one view to another view

```
   public func pinView(_ view: UIView, to scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.pin(to: scrollView)
    }

    public func pin(to view: UIView) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            ])
    }
```

Comment: Adding programmatically ?

Comment: Yeah, adding `scrollView` programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use below methods for get exact size of screen accordingly iPhone. 
Hope using this method, your problem solved. If you have doubt Please comment here.

```
//MARK: - Main Screen Width

func getScreenWidth() -> CGFloat{
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
}

//MARK: - Main Screen Height
func getScreenHeight() -> CGFloat{
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pin your `scrollView` to `view` instead of setting its `frame`.

Add a constraint that sets the width of the `contentView` equal to the width of the `scrollView`:

```
contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: woow solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` load your ui from `storyboard` or `nib`. And size depend on what you select in `Interface Builder`.

You can initialize ui in `viewWillAppear` and add a variable `isInitialized` .

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if !isInitialized {
        isInitialized = true
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

Answer (score 0):

make one subview horizontally center (using autolayout constraint) to a scrollview in interface builder or by programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there are a couple of ways you can fix this:

1.- in the storyboard go to your view and you're going to hold the left click in your scroll view and release it over the main view, then you'll click equal width

2.- in the view did load put

```
self.scrollViewName.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the contentInset on the scrollView, and it will adjust the content size of the scrolling area within the scrollView, here is a quick example

```
scrollView.contentInset UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: padding)
```

That should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting constraints from `viewDidLoad`, but view is not properly layout in this method. You should set constraint when lay out of views is done. So you should set constraints in :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // set constraints here 
}
```

And you can use a variable to check if constraints are already added.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, may be you are not able to change frame because of autoresizing, So try to write following code in `viewDidAppear` method

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

super.viewDidAppear(animated)

   // Set the frame of scrollview

   self.scrollViewName.frame = CGRectMake(self.scrollViewName.frame.origin.x, 
   self.scrollViewName.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

}
```